# Wordpress slider with video

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for slider that works with images and video. I tried many but they do not have this functionality. I can possibly do it myself (based on posts in category and jquery) - it's not a big problem, but the problem is when on video slide person click on play - slideshow has to stop.

Where I find something like that (preferred free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Flexslider and the awesome Flexslider 2.

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/video.html